# formatting a json array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a json array of objects.

My array is

```
var array=[{a:1,b:2,id:apple},{a:5,b:10,id:banana}]
```

I want to output it so that the array is of format:

```
[{source:apple, target:a ,value:1},{source:apple, target:b ,value:2},{source:banana, target:a ,value:5},{source:banana, target:b ,value:10}]
```

Help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and `Object.keys()` to get this result.

```js
var array=[{a:1,b:2,id:'apple'},{a:5,b:10,id:'banana'}];

var result = array.reduce(function(r, e) {
  Object.keys(e).forEach(function(k) {
    if(k != 'id') r.push({source: e.id, target:k ,value:e[k]}) 
  })
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you ..Your answer is correct. But does not work if i have 500 key values pairs in a single object.

Comment: It should be working no matter of number of properties https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1116/

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just use `JSON.stringify(array)`

Answer (score 0):

A native (untested)solution would be:

```js
function myFormat(objects){
  var formated = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
    if(!objects[i].hasOwnProperty('id'))continue;

    var fObj = [];
    for(var key in objects[i]){
      if(key == 'id')continue;

      formated.push({
        source: objects[i].id, 
        target: key, 
        value: objects[i][key]
      });
    }
  }
  return formated;
}

var array=[{a:1,b:2,id:'apple'},{a:5,b:10,id:'banana'}];
console.log(myFormat(array));
```